# Read all the columns of a dataframe as characters, by means of `read.csv`

Tags: r, csv, read.csv

I could use `colClasses` but it has length equal to the number of imported columns, which I don't know, since I'm automatically importing csv files. Supposing my dataset columns are 5:

```
colClasses=rep("character",5)
```

How can I read all the columns of the dataframe as characters, without specifying the number of columns?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From `?read.csv`:

> colClasses
> character. A vector of classes to be assumed for the columns. If unnamed, recycled as necessary.

Recycled means that it will be applied to as many columns as you have. So there's no need to specify the number of columns - you can just use:

```
read.csv(colClasses = "character")
```